# Complicated XML Parse to Labels

Tags: ios, xml

Hi guys Im a newbie iOS Pragrammer and I have to parse the "Value" tags of this XML in some labels.
Im getting confused by the identical tags.
I don't expect solutions, it just would be great if someone could give me an explanation of how to go forward to make the code for this XML example.
I thank for any response and help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Statistics xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="">
<Statistics>
<Statistic>
  <Name>heute</Name>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Bestellungen heute</Name>
    <Value>12</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Umsatz heute netto</Name>
    <Value>7225,97</Value>
  </Statistic>
</Statistic>
<Statistic>
  <Name>Allgemein</Name>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Online</Name>
    <Value>2495</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Lager</Name>
    <Value>448</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Auslauf</Name>
    <Value>29</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Keine Features</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Reservierungen</Name>
    <Value>163</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Aufträge</Name>
    <Value>44100</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Abholer</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Vorkasse</Name>
    <Value>8</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Nachnahme</Name>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Kreditkarte</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Paypal</Name>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Sofortüberweisung</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Finanzierung</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Amazon</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Neue Emails</Name>
    <Value>28</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Fragen</Name>
    <Value>10</Value>
  </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
    <Name>Termine</Name>
    <Value>4</Value>
  </Statistic>
</Statistic>
```

Comment: What are you looking to get out? An array of dictionaries? Can you show your code so far...

Comment: I want to get the content of the Value tags, sorry but I have no own code yet and looked for tutorials.. I only found examples for XML's which have simple structure without many tags with the same name..

Comment: So you just want one big array of `NSNumber` instances for each of the `Value` keys? Without being clear of your goal you will find it hard to write an XMP parser delegate...

Comment: what would be your steps to get all Values in different labels? thx for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create an `NSXMLParser` instance and a class to act as its `delegate`. You will get callbacks about the keys that were found and the text that they contain. If you don't care about most keys then you can ignore them. For the keys you do care about, store the received text and, each time you are told a key has been completed, add the result to an `NSMutableArray`.

Now, when the parsing is complete you have an array full of `Value`s.

Displaying these values on labels is harder than using a `UITableView`, so look at that instead. You can use the array as the data source as it gives you the `count` of rows you need and can be accessed using the table view `indexPath.row` to get the `Value` to display for each row (and rows contain labels that you can use).